# Поиск и замена строки в названии и содержимом файлов и папок через powershell

Tags: powershell

Хочу автоматизировать рутинные действия с помощью скрипта на PowerShell. Использую старый работающий скрипт для поиска строк:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\git\*' -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern 'String'
```

Пытаюсь доработать его, чтобы все найденные строки он менял, например, с String на NewString.

```
$PathToDirectory='D:\git\*'
$FirstString='String'
$SecondString='NewString'

Get-ChildItem -Path $PathToDirectory -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $FirstString | ForEach-Object {
     $filePath = $_.Path
     $lineNumber = $_.LineNumber
     $newLine = $_.Line -replace $FirstString, $SecondString
     $content = Get-Content $filePath
     $content[$lineNumber - 1] = $newLine
     $content | Set-Content $filePath
 }
```

В дебаге видно, что путь неправильный в ForEach (`C:\Users\User\InputStream`). Если создать/скопировать папку по этому пути, то будет ругаться, что это не файл, а директория. Если указать путь до файла в этой папке, то скрипт отрабатывает, но ни название ни строки в файле/папке не меняются. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Есть ещё скрипт, который находит и удаляет все файлы с расширением, например, .pdb, может кому-то поможет. Думаю, что на основе него частично тоже можно что-то написать. 

Write-Host "Запуск очистки от файлов .pbd"
$temp="0"
$PathToDir="D:\git"
Push-Location "$PathToDir"
foreach($File in Get-ChildItem -Path "$PathToDir" -Recurse -File)
 {
  [Boolean]$validExt = ($File.Extension -eq ".pdb")
  if($validExt)
  {
   $temp=$File.FullName
            
            Write-Host "Remove $temp"
            Remove-Item -Path "$temp" -Force
  }
  
 }
Write-Host "All removed"
Pop-Location

Comment: Частично можно сделать вручную через notepad++ через Поиск -> Найти в файлах...

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал на примере одного файла, код вроде верный, но Get-ChildItem ищет и файлы и папки, а судя по названию папки и параметру Recurse, я предполагаю, что подпапок там навалом, потому может и происходит данная проблема.
Быть может попробовать так:

```
$PathToDirectory='D:\git\'
$FirstString='String'
$SecondString='NewString'

Get-ChildItem -Path $PathToDirectory -Recurse -File| Select-String -Pattern $FirstString | ForEach-Object {
     $filePath = $_.Path
     $lineNumber = $_.LineNumber
     $newLine = $_.Line -replace $FirstString, $SecondString
     [Array]$content = Get-Content $filePath
     $content[$lineNumber - 1] = $newLine
     $content | Set-Content $filePath
  }
```

Comment: Не сработало. Вот ошибки: InvalidOperation: D:\User\Programming\Scripts\PowerShell\Поиск строки по файлам и замена строки.ps1:12:6
12 | $content[$lineNumber - 1] = $newLine
| Unable to index into an object of type "System.String".
Set-Content: D:\User\Programming\Scripts\PowerShell\Поиск строки по файлам и замена строки.ps1:13:17
13 | $content | Set-Content $filePath
| The process cannot access the file 'D:\git\string — копия.txt' because it is being used by another process.
InvalidOperation: D:\User\Programming\Scripts\PowerShell\Поиск строки по файлам и замена строки.ps1:12:6

Comment: Использовал тестовую папку. Количество папок и подпапок 3, количество файлов 6.

Comment: первая ошибка это то, что файл состоит из одной строки и к нему невозможно работать с ним как с массивом по индексам, попробуй [array]$Content = Get-Content $filePath
Вторая ошибка это файл, в который пытаешься писать - занят другим процессом.

Comment: Invalid Operation исчез, а доступ к файлам остаётся. Там для каждого найденного файла такая ошибка. А каким они заняты другим процессом, если я только запускаю скрипт?

Comment: Ну чудес не бывает **because it is being used by another process.**
Файл открыт в каком-то ещё приложении, которое не позволяет произвести запись в файл, учитывая, что это Git, в том же гите или какой-нить vscode.
Скопируй данные файлы в какую-нить отвлеченную директорию и произведи эксперимент в ней.

Comment: Папку git я создал с нуля для примера, а файлы вообще не трогал. Разве что саму папку в проводнике открыл. А у тебя этот скрипт без ошибок срабатывает? Через что и как запускаешь?